# guild not defined | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have this problem that says guild not defined. I had the same problem with members but I fixed it by adding a constant. I'm pretty new to javascript and node.js. Can anybody help? I even tried looking into index.js and copying the constants above and it didn't work.

```js
const member = guild.member.first(message.author);
               ^

ReferenceError: guild is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\bot1\commands\prune.js:7:16)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:986:32)[39m
[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:14)[39m
[90m    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1026:19)[39m
[90m    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:72:18)[39m
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\bot1\index.js:11:18)
[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1138:30)[39m
[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:10)[39m
```

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const member = guild.member.first(message.author);
const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

const permissions = new Permissions([
    'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
]);

module.exports = {
    name: 'prune',
    description: 'prune up to 99 messages.',
    execute(message, args) {
        const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1
    
        if (member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) 
        {

            if (isNaN(amount)) {
                return message.channel.send('That\'s not a valid number');
            } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
                return message.channel.send('You need to input a number between 1 and 99.');
            }

            message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send('There was an error trying to prune messages in this channel.');
        })

        if (!member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
        {
            message.channel.send("You dont have the required permissions to execute this command")
        }

        };
    }
};
```

Comment: You've never defined guild in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `member` within the `execute()` function since you need to get the GuildMember object out of `message`

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const { Permissions } = require('discord.js');

const permissions = new Permissions([
    'MANAGE_MESSAGES',
]);

module.exports = {
    name: 'prune',
    description: 'prune up to 99 messages.',
    execute(message, args) {
        const member = message.member;
        const amount = parseInt(args[0]) + 1
    
        if (member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')) 
        {

            if (isNaN(amount)) {
                return message.channel.send('That\'s not a valid number');
            } else if (amount <= 1 || amount > 100) {
                return message.channel.send('You need to input a number between 1 and 99.');
            }

            message.channel.bulkDelete(amount, true).catch(err => {
            console.error(err);
            message.channel.send('There was an error trying to prune messages in this channel.');
        })

        if (!member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES'))
        {
            message.channel.send("You dont have the required permissions to execute this command")
        }

        };
    }
};
```

Comment: thank you really much. i still dont understand this fully but ill try searching it up